# Has anyone tried modelling in blender with VR headset?

Tags: modeling, vr

As I continue to use blender professionally as a medium between autodesk revit architecture and 3D printing (to tweak the model for print stability) I get increasingly frustrated with limitations of mouse and keyboard for navigation so I am looking into weather it's worth buying VR headset to accelerate my work.
Has anyone tried modelling in blender in VR? Maybe you've heard feedback, issues ect.?

Would love everyone's thoughts on this one

Comment: I suspect that your question is going to be closed as any answers would be opinion-based. You'd probably be better starting a thread in somewhere like [blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/).